# What formats of audio or video files can store bookmarks?

Tags: audio, mp3, bookmarks

Does mp3 file format allows me to store timestamps as named tags in the play of an mp3 file? For example, I want to bookmark places in an audio book, corresponding to the bookmarks/outlines of its pdf file, to signify the beginning of chapters and sections and any place that interests me.

Can other formats of audio or video files store bookmarks?

Answer (score 2):

[ID3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3) standard/container actually has [chapter support](https://mutagen-specs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/id3/id3v2-chapters-1.0.html) and it's used for mentioned `.mp3`s. It isn't supported widely across all applications, though.

As for how to add them, I found this tool - [Pineapple Chapter Tool](https://github.com/BLumia/pineapple-chapter-tool). You'll need to compile it yourself and it has no opinions, but might be worth a try. It also [lists](https://github.com/BLumia/pineapple-chapter-tool#for-the-players) which of popular media players support the chapter tags, but the info may be outdated as this README hasn't been touched for at least 2 years.

If you want to go for videos instead, more formats support chapters for sure. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_container_formats) comparison chart lists some: `.mkv`, `.mov`, `.wmv`, `.f4v`, `.flv`, `.webm` and incomplete support for `.mp4`, `.m4v`, `.avi` out of the commonly used ones. [Drax](https://www.videohelp.com/software/Drax) could help you to add them as an example of a GUI application.

Comment: There are also very few examples of people doing it with ffmpeg: https://dev.to/montekaka/add-chapter-markers-to-podcast-audio-using-ffmpeg-3c46 but I can't test them at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

> Does mp3 file format allows me to store timestamps as named tags in the play of an mp3 file?

No, it is not in the specification.

> Can other formats of audio or video files store bookmarks?

Yes, for example MKV can store "chapters". To create them, see [this FFMpeg page](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Metadata-1):

> `ffmpeg -i INPUT -i FFMETADATAFILE -map_metadata 1 -codec copy OUTPUT`
> where `FFMETADATAFILE` is like:
>
> ```
> ;FFMETADATA1
> title=bike\\shed
> ;this is a comment
> artist=FFmpeg troll team
>
> [CHAPTER]
> TIMEBASE=1/1000
> START=0
> #chapter ends at 0:01:00
> END=60000
> title=chapter \#1
> [STREAM]
> title=multi\
> line
> ```

Comment: Thanks. Can sections be created under chapters?

Comment: @Tim you can have [nested chapters in MKV](https://www.matroska.org/technical/chapters.html#nested-chapters) which can function as sections.

Comment: thanks. what software applications are recommended for adding, editing, and deleting bookmarks in an MKV file? I am using Linux.

Comment: @Tim `ffmpeg` can work, `mkvpropedit` can work, ... too many to list.